# Swipe down and up on UIView working but scrollview hindering it swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, gesture

I have searched google but unfortunately was not able to find the solution to my query so finally i thought to post it here. I have a UIViewController that contains a ScrollView which has UIView and a tableView. On that UIView I have applied the gestures to it: Swipe right , Left , Up and Down and also tap gesture. The Right , Left and Tap gestures are working fine and but the up and down gesture are not working (not getting recognized). This is due the fact that they are being contained in a scrollView and when the swipe Up and Down gestures are made the scrollview goes Up and Down and hence hindering the swipe gestures applied to the UIView. Screen shots of the scenario has been attached. Any help will be appreciated.

**Now My question is :** when clicked (scroll performed) on tableView, the cells should be scrollable and at that time the entire view should not scroll and when gestures are performed on the UIView containing UIImage (up and down swipe gesture) the entire view should not scroll again. Hope I was able to convey my query.

[image]

// Here is the entire class code.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewVC: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var names = ["Anurag","Tushar","Deepamkar","Karnail","Anurag","Tushar","Deepamkar","Karnail","Anurag","Tushar","Deepamkar","Karnail","Anurag","Tushar","Deepamkar","Karnail","Anurag","Tushar","Deepamkar","Karnail"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
        self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
        self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
        self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToTapGesture))
        self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

  @objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
                print("Swiped right")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
                print("Swiped down")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                print("Swiped left")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
                print("Swiped up")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func respondToTapGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture is UITapGestureRecognizer {
           print("Tapped")
        }
    }
}

extension TableViewVC : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
            cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
            return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you put TableView and UIView inside the scrollview..? Just get those out of scrollview and i guess your code will work.

Comment: @ShrutiThombre In this UI there is a a topView (missing in the UI) above headerView (that is here contains the UIimageView). So i want everything to be scrolled including the topView,HeadeView and TableView and enabling the gestures (up and down on the headerView). But when swiped up and down on the headerView the scrolling is being called of scrollView and swipe geswtures not getting called. That is the problem and hence I have to use scrolll view so that all views are scrollable.

Comment: Why not set this UIView as the UITableView header?

Comment: @TalCohen Did that but the swipe gestures (up and down) when done on the header view scrolls the tableView and swipe on header view again are not being called.

Comment: What about put the view on top of the scroll view?

Comment: @TalCohen Then that View will not be scrollable anymore and the scenario is that everting should be scrollable including topView, tableView, headerView (having swipe up and down gesture working)

Answer (score 0):

Implement UISwipeGestureRecognizer Delegate

```
 let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
swipeRight.delegate = self
    self.headerView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```